# Bundle Items not including VAT in Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, vat

A bundled item with 2 options (colour), is including VAT in the total, but not in the individual bundled items.

[image: see photo]

Using FireCheckout. I should clarify VAT is included in the bundled items catalog/product page, but it's just not showing in checkout.

Comment: can you please show the vat configuration under system configuration -> calculation settings ?

Comment: @ChristopheFerreboeuf Many thanks for your reply. Here is the VAT configuration: https://i.imgur.com/9O04lb4.png

Answer (score 0):

Option could be to set the price in your catalog as including tax but I do not really know the tax system in UK.

Else, there is not really possibility out of the box to display tax for bundled subproducts as they normally do not have a tax class if I remember correctly. If you are up for some development, you can hook during the rendering and retrieve the tax to apply and to display the price with taxes instead of the catalog price.